# How to use a method from an already to Cotainer put JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jlabel

I have to programm a Shikaku-Game and I have no the problem that I can not use one of the setLine-Methods from the ViewIcon-Class in the mouseReleased-Method of the class MyMouseAdapter.
Do you know a way how to use one of the methods?

Thanks and Cheers,
Me

Class MouseMain and Class MyMouseAdapter:

```
class MouseMain extends JFrame{

Container cont;

public MouseMain () {
    super("Test");
    cont = getContentPane();
    p1 = new defaultPaterns(2);
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 1, 1));
    for (int i = 0; i < gameSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gameSize; j++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(new ViewIcon());
            label.setName (j + ";" + i);
            label.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter());
            p1.add(label);
            myLabels[j][i] = label;
        }
    }
    cont.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER );

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    cont.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setVisible(true);
}

public class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        lastEntered = e.getComponent();
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        mousePressed = e.getComponent();
        coordPressed = new Coordinate(mousePressed.getName());
        System.out.println("mousePressed " + mousePressed.getName());
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseReleased = lastEntered;
        coordReleased = new Coordinate(mouseReleased.getName());
        System.out.println("mouseReleased " + mouseReleased.getName());
        if (mouseReleased.getName().equals("0;0")) {
            mouseReleased.setForeground(Color.RED);
            mouseReleased.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Class ViewIcon:

```
class ViewIcon extends JLabel implements Icon {

    Graphics2D g2;
    int width;
    int height;

public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {

    g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    width = c.getWidth();
    height = c.getHeight();
    g2.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
}

public void setLeftLine() {

    g2.setStroke (new BasicStroke (10));
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.drawLine(0, 0, 0, height);
}

}
```

Comment: That's not what I'd call a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ViewIcon extends JLabel implements Icon {
```

Don't extend JLabel. All your code is doing is implementing the Icon interface.

> I can not use one of the setLine-Methods from the ViewIcon-Class

Custom painting should only be done in the paintIcon(...) method. You should NEVER invoke a painting method directly.

If you want to change the appearance of your painting then you need to set properties of the Icon. For example to paint the top line you rename and change your `setTopLine(...)` method to look something like:

```
public void setTopLinePainted(boolean topLinePainted)
{
    this.topLinePainted = topLinePainted;
}
```

Then in the paintIcon(...) method you have code like:

```
g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

if (topLinePainted)
{
    g2.setStroke (new BasicStroke (10));
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.drawLine(0, 0, width, 0);
}
```

Then in your mouseReleased(...) code you do something like:

```
JLabel label = (JLabel)lastEntered;
ViewIcon icon = (ViewIcon)label.getIcon();
icon.setTopLinePainted( true );
label.repaint();
```

Comment: awesome !! Thanks for your help camickr. I was stuck in this problem for about 10 hours and now it just works ! crazy ! :)